# Subset data frame in R given grouping length criterium

Tags: r

I'm working on some exercises based on this [dataset](https://github.com/bigtoast/comp-data/blob/master/assign-2/outcome-of-care-measures.csv).

There's a `State` column listing the rate of deaths per month by heart attack for each hospital of the state (column 11):

```
> table(data$State)

 AK  AL  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  FL  GA  GU  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS  KY   
 17  98  77  77 341  72  32   8   6 180 132   1  19 109  30 179 124 118  96
```

Now I try to filter out these states where at least 20 values are available:

```
> table(data$State)>20

   AK    AL    AR    AZ    CA    CO    CT    DC    DE    FL    GA    GU     
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So using `subset` I try to get a subset of data based on the above conditions, but that gives me a result I can't follow:

```
> data_subset <- subset(data, table(data$State)>20)
> table(data_subset$State)

 AK  AL  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  FL  GA  GU  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS  KY   
 14  84  66  65 288  64  25   8   5 155 109   1  19  93  24 153 107 100  83
```

Why am I getting `AK 14`, when I would expect that state to be filtered out by the condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach to filter out the data with less than 20 rows:

```
tab <- table(data$State)
data[data$State %in% names(tab)[tab > 19], ]
```

Your code

```
subset(data, table(data$State)>20)
```

does not work because `table(data$State)>20` returns a boolean vector of length `length(table$State)`. In your data, the boolean vector is shorter than the number of rows in your data frame. Due to vector recycling, the vector is combined with itself until the longer length is reached. E.g., have a look at `(1:3)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`.

Comment: Are you writing on purpose `...[tab > 19], ]` rather than `[ , ...[tab > 19]]`? Also, do you see what's going wrong with my solution?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this subtlety. Is it possible to rewrite your solution avoiding the `%in%` operator?